# how to echo $success variable from another php page

Tags: php, html

I am inserting values to a db using a form in a modal box, it all works fine except for the success pop up.

The query gets run on a funtions.php page

```
//create account
if (isset($_POST['btn-signup'])){
    $firstname = test_input($_POST['firstname']);
    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $pass = test_input($_POST['password']);
    $cpass = test_input($_POST['confirm_password']);

    if ($pass == $cpass){
        $password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $signupQuery = "INSERT INTO draadlozeAccount (firstname, email, pass) VALUES 
        ('$firstname','$email','$password')";
        $signupResult = $conn->query($signupQuery);
        if (!$signupResult) {
            echo $conn->error;
            $conn->close();

        } else {
            $success = '<div class="notification pos-right pos-bottom col-sm-4 col-md-3" data-animation="from-bottom" data-notification-link="trigger">
                                <div class="boxed boxed--border border--round box-shadow">
                                    <img alt="avatar" class="image--sm" src="img/logo.png" />
                                    <div class="text-block">
                                        <h5>Success</h5>
                                        <p>
                                           Your account has been created successfully. You will receive an email soon.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>';
        }
    }

}
```

Then on index.php I echo out success

```
                    <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) {
                        echo $success;
                    }
                    ?>
```

My question is then why is my success window not coming up? What am I missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is, in your `function.php` file

```
$_SESSION['success'] = "<div ...... ";
```

And in your `index.php`

```
if (isset($_SESSION['success']){
    echo $_SESSION['success'];
}
```

But i recommend something like in you `function.php`

```
$_SESSION['success'] = true;
```

And in your `index.php`

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['success']){
    ?>
    <div ............... your html ...... />
    <?php
}
```

use specific names other than `success`, like `signupsuccess`

Comment: Thank you mate, your answer helped met tweak my code and it is all working now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the variable scopes? Variable is limited to current page only. You can use session variables to maintain state management. Session variables are limited to current session.

```
} else {
        $_SESSION['success'] = '<div class="notification pos-right pos-bottom col-sm-4 col-md-3" data-animation="from-bottom" data-notification-link="trigger">
                            <div class="boxed boxed--border border--round box-shadow">
                                <img alt="avatar" class="image--sm" src="img/logo.png" />
                                <div class="text-block">
                                    <h5>Success</h5>
                                    <p>
                                       Your account has been created successfully. You will receive an email soon.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>';
    }
```

and use it like this

```
echo $_SESSION['success'];
```

Comment: Hi, yes I understand this, but this does not make any difference. My form is still submitted and data posted but no notification shows up

Comment: do debug bro , use die() or exit() functions to check the code flow. You are developer and you can't ask questions  like that.

Comment: question are all about learning buddy. Asking the question helped me sort out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you are trying to print a variable set in another file, which is impossible. At the end of a script, all the declarations are burnt, nothing remains available for the script called by the page the user browses next.

The ir are only three ways to have your data stil available in the next page :

- Persist it in your database then retrieve it later.
- Send it to the page with the HTTP request as GET or POST.
- Use sessions and store `$success` as a session variable in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: I start sessions at the top, and then echo $_SESSION['success'] on the index file, but the it is like the model is never triggered, I have added my form code to the question

Comment: Your code shows that you assign `$success` in one page and try to print `$success` on another. There aren't session variables. I don't see your form code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively place your success-html-code-snippet in a seperate file e.g. "success-snippet.inc.html" and then get the content with "file_get_contents()" when needed. If you prefer session as mentioned above, you must start the session previously.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need a form or ajax
ajax code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#senden").click(function(){
  var daten = $('#formular').serialize();
        $.ajax({
   url: "test.php",
   type: 'post',
   data: daten,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(result){
    $("#result").val(result.passwort);
    $('#test').html(result.test);
   },
   error: function(xhr, status){
    console.log('AJAX returned ' + status);
   }
  });
    });
});
```

You can look on your own how to include and use it.